# Protractor JS pre-processors

Tags: node.js, angularjs, testing, protractor

I am aware that there is the option within Karma to use pre-processors however, in Protractor I can't see the same sort of thing. I am currently using the onPrepare option but I am wondering if it is possible / currently if there is a  way to have the a npm module to always run prior (basically the same as the onPrepare) but by the config and not having to do any require etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like scripts in your package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install",
    "pretest": "npm install",
    "test": "karma start test/karma.conf.js",
    "test-single-run": "karma start test/karma.conf.js  --single-run",
    "preupdate-webdriver": "npm install",
    "update-webdriver": "webdriver-manager update",
    "preprotractor": "npm run update-webdriver && node setUp.js",
    "protractor": "protractor test/protractor-conf.js",
    "postprotractor": "node tearDown.js",
}
```

By saying 'npm run protractor' in your cmd, both scripts in pre-(setUp.js) and postprotractor (tearDown.js) will be run before and after your e2e tests.